# Why is my code not working in my script but runs fine using chromium developer console?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I've used the request module to login to a site and navigate to a page with some data I want to print out to the console, If I am on the page in my browser and put this code into the console the data prints out just how I want it.

```
Array.from($("tbody")[0].children).forEach((el, index) => {
    if (index % 2 == 0) {
        console.log(el.children[1].textContent);
    }
});
```

This is the relevant code

```
const request = require('request-promise').defaults({ jar : true });
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const my_site = 'https://example.com';
const html = await request.get(my_site);
const $ = cheerio.load(html);

Array.from($("tbody")[0].children).forEach((el, index) => {
    if (index % 2 == 0) {
        console.log(el.children[1].textContent);
    }
});
```

Running the code above returns the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
    at Array.from.forEach (/home/meano/Desktop/serverless/utils/scrape.js:30:36)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at main (/home/meano/Desktop/serverless/utils/scrape.js:28:44)
```

Comment: in which line you got the error ? console or array.from ?

Comment: array.from, I'm thinking maybe I haven't defined $ correctly?

Comment: can I suggest you a new method ?

Comment: Yeah I did thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 0):

This got me the data I wanted

```
const html = await request.get(my_site);
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
let body = $("tbody").text()
console.log(body)
```